# Problem with a <div> and <button> on lower resolutions

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm making a text based RPG, everything works fine but when i have lots of text inside the buttons, on lower resolutions (iphone 5, 5se for example) , my buttons get pushed out of the box (div).

Any idea?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="text">Text</div>
  <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Option 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Option 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Option 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Option 1</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #474a56;
}

.container{
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 950px;
  max-width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-grid{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 18px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.btn{
  font-family: 'Roboto mono', monospace;
  color: white;
  background-color: #474a56;
  border: 1px solid #d3d5fd;
  border-radius: 3.8px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming this is an issue with the font size: in that case, we can use CSS media queries (which can dynamically adjust properties based on certain factors).

In your case, we can do something like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) { /* Screens smaller than 720px */
    div, button {
        font-size: 0.7rem;
        padding: 5px;

        ...

        foo: bar;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .foo {
        ...
    }

    #bar {
        ...
    }
}
```

(Make sure to put this code at the bottom, from biggest screen to smallest, in order for cascading to override.)

**Extra notes**

Media queries effectively act as a container for more styles, if the condition is met. I like to think of it as an inline HTML `<style>` tag.

[Here](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/)'s the W3 spec and [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)'s some W3schools examples.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `max-width` from your `.container` class.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #474a56;
}

.container {
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 950px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 2%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 2px;
  text-align: center;
}

.btn-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  gap: 18px;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.btn {
  font-family: 'Roboto mono', monospace;
  color: white;
  background-color: #474a56;
  border: 1px solid #d3d5fd;
  border-radius: 3.8px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="text">Text</div>
  <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam et porro a fuga, totam, quidem quibusdam dolores iste illum ipsam quia autem alias error, eaque dicta numquam nulla debitis quis.</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Option 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Option 1</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn"> Option 1</button>

  </div>
</div>
```